Adding shared_prefrences package to flutter gives error
So i was making a project and i wanted to save the data locally. So i added shared preferences package to my flutter project step by step as shown in this link: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences/install and it also reflected in my pubspec.yaml file under the dependencies . But when i run flutter run it gives this error:
Execution failed for task ':shared_preferences_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    Could not resolve all files for configuration    :shared_preferences_android:androidJdkImage.
    Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes     {artifactType=\_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar,
    org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.

I tried checking the version of my android sdk and its up-to-date and my API level is 34 and also updated command line tools to the latest but nothing works
My build.gradle
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    }

    android {
    namespace = "com.example.billionaireapp"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.example.billionaireapp"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://flutter.dev/to/review-gradle-config.
        minSdk = flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutter.versionCode
        versionName = flutter.versionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
    }

    flutter {
    source = "../.."
    }

pubspec.yaml
    name: billionaireapp
    description: "A new Flutter project."
    publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

    version: 1.0.0+1

    environment:
      sdk: ^3.5.4


    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
      shared_preferences: ^2.3.3

    dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter

      flutter_lints: ^4.0.0

    flutter:

      uses-material-design: true


Have you tried this? If not, please try it.
in terminal , root of project
cd android
./gradlew clean
cd ..
flutter clean
flutter pub get

and try run project again

This is more of a comment/question to the OPs question then an answer.  To become an answer, recommend indicating more supporting information and why this will fix the problem.  Ex.  Version X of blah has a known bug that requires the programmer to manually do Y etc...

I cant comment , because of i have less than 50 reputation to . I tried my best for help him/her.
